# When querying Facebook's API with a date range, are both createdDate and lastUpdatedDate considered?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

When querying the Facebook Graph API for data within a date range, are 'SINCE' and 'UNTIL' query params compared to an objects createdDate only, or are they also compared to lastUpdatedDate?

Answer (score 1):

Querying Posts only the createDate is checked. If you need the "update" information your app needs a RTU subscription.